# javascript not working when updating the panel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

There are several tabs in my page and in one tab I am trying to change the other drop down when I am selecting the first drop down. I am using updatepanel and script manager for that. The problem is I wrote a datepicker javascript function and it works fine for the first time if i do not select the drop down box but when I select the drop down box the javacript does not work. It will be helpful if someone can identify what I am doing wrong.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat ="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div id="requestHistory" class="tab-pane">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelCRHistory" runat="server" CssClass="row"     DefaultButton="btnSearch" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
  <div class="colmd-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 responsive-filterbar">
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpCRHistoryFramework" ClientIDMode="AutoID" DataTextField="title" DataValueField="frameworkID" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCRHistoryFramework_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem  Selected="true" Text ="--Framework--" value="0" ></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>                
  </div>
  <div class="colmd-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 responsive-filterbar">
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpCRHSkillName" ClientIDMode="AutoID" DataTextField="skillName" DataValueField="skillID" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCRHSkillName_SelectedIndexChanged">
   </asp:DropDownList>
   </div>
   <div class="colmd-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 responsive-filterbar">
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpCRHLevel" ClientIDMode="AutoID"  CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCRHLevel_SelectedIndexChanged">
   </asp:DropDownList>
   </div>

   <div class="colmd-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 responsive-filterbar input-group date" style="padding-left: 15px;" id="dpDate">
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFromDate" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control datepicker" placeholder="0"></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>

   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtToDate" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control datepicker" placeholder="0"></asp:TextBox>
             <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
             </span>
         </div><br /><br />
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 responsive-filterbar">
          <div class="input-group">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="canidateRequestHistorySearchTextBox" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="canidateRequestHistorySearchLinkButton" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btncandidateRequestHistorySearch" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CausesValidation="false" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></asp:LinkButton>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
         <br/><br/>
         </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void drpCRHistoryFramework_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frameworkID = Convert.ToInt32(drpCRHistoryFramework.SelectedValue);
    drpCRHSkillName.DataSource = CompetencyManager.GetCompetencyByFrameworkAndMentoringRequests(((int)Session[CommonHelper.Constants.CURRENT_CANDIDATE]), frameworkID);
    drpCRHSkillName.DataBind();
    drpCRHSkillName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Competency --", "0"));
    string script = @"
        $(function () { // will trigger when the document is ready
            $('.datepicker').datepicker(); //Initialise any date pickers
        })";
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "alert", script, true);
    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanelCRHistory, UpdatePanelCRHistory.GetType(), "alert",script, true);
    UpdatePanelCRHistory.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you set your javascript only to be called when the page is ready. When you do an update using update panel your page isn't loaded again, but separate sections are updated. These sections contain html that needs your javascript function to initialize the controls again.

You can trigger the initialize controls for both initial load as for updated update panels using the following (typing this by head on a MacBook so can't test it) by adding it to the bottom of your master-page or at the bottom of a specific page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PartialPostBackFinished(sender, args) {
    var updatePanels = args.get_panelsUpdated();
    for (i = 0; i < updatedPanels.length; i++) {
        //Do whatever needs to be triggered for each updated update panel
        InitializeControls(updatedPanels[i]);
    }
}

function InitializeControls(container) {
    $('.datepicker', container).datepicker(); //Initialise any date pickers
}

if (Sys != undefined) {
    //There's a ScriptManager on the page
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(PartialPostBackFinished);

    if (!prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
        //Trigger initialization for synchronous post back triggered outside updatepanels
        InitializeControls(document);
    }
}
else {
    //Trigger initialization for pages without ScriptManager
    InitializeControls(document);
}
</script>
```

This will also replace the need to RegisterClientScriptBlock, so remove that from your code-behind.